# Didn't find class "com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider"

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, facebook

I'm trying tu run on Android (4.4.2 - KitKat) using react-native-fbsdk but I have problems using it.

I found a similar questions but doesn't solve it:

https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues/365
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException after add android Facebook SDK to the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636294/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception-after-add-android-face)

Console Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.domestika, PID: 1365
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.domestika-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.domestika-2, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.marketing.internal.MarketingInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.domestika-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.domestika-2, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for help.